# I can't initialize a struct values in C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have this variable:

```
struct mat{
    int row;
    int column;
};
vector<bool> aux;
```

In the main function I initialize a vector of mat's by this way:

```
int main(){
    int n,r,c;
    char s;
    cin >> n;
    vector<mat> matrices = vector<mat> (27);
    aux = vector<bool> (32,false);
    for(int i=0; i<n;++i) {
        cin >> s >> r >> c;
        matrices[s-'A'].row = r;
        matrices[s-'A'].column = c;
        aux[s-'A'] = true;
}
```

But when I left the `for` loop, I call a function which writes the vector matrices in shell:

```
void writeMatrices(vector<mat>& matrices){
    for(int i = 0; i < aux.size(); ++i){
        if(aux[i]) {
            cout << char ('A'+i) << " Rows: " << matrices[i+'A'].row << " Columns: " << matrices[i+'A'].column << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And I only obtain 0's.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Why `integer - 'A'` can't you do it the normal way?

Comment: what were the inputs for s, r, and c?  How do you know that s - 'A' will give a reasonable result?  You aren't checking for input stream errors either.  I suggest that you debug it a bit, and then update the question with the values of your inputs.

Comment: For one thing, you should start by providing initial values for all variables, and a default constructor for your struct.  ( mat (int r, c) : row(r), column(c) {} ).  Then debug and check the values as you are stepping through the code.  Let us know the results.  You might be causing undefined behavior if the s - 'R' doesn't return a reasonable value. Additionally your loop does not limit you to trying to write to only 27 elements (or fewer) of the vector.

Comment: `vector<mat> matrices = vector<mat> (27)` just needs to be `vector<mat> matrices(27)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are incorrectly adding the value of `'A'` to your index when reading it back out.  The code for `writeMatrices` should be this instead:

```
void writeMatrices(vector<mat>& matrices){
    for(int i = 0; i < aux.size(); ++i){
        if(aux[i]) {
            cout << char ('A'+i) 
                 // note that the index for matrices should be i, not i+'A' !
                 << " Rows: "    << matrices[i].row 
                 << " Columns: " << matrices[i].column 
                 << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Used with this input data:

```
6
A 1 2
B 2 3
C 3 4
D 4 5
E 5 6
F 6 7
```

we now get this output:

```
A Rows: 1 Columns: 2
B Rows: 2 Columns: 3
C Rows: 3 Columns: 4
D Rows: 4 Columns: 5
E Rows: 5 Columns: 6
F Rows: 6 Columns: 7
```

Some error checking within your code would have enabled you to spot this problem sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrices collection has 27 elements.  Your collection of bool (aux) has 32 elements, which is more than the size or your matrices collection.  Your for loop is executing "n" times which could be anything depending on input.  Your collection indexer is "s-'A'" which I assume you're inputting s like "A,B,C,D,..."  All in all this is a very strange, haphazard and unreliable way to work with collections.  You should instead have just 1 max size and 1 loop indexer variable and use it for everything.  Or start with empty collections and use "push_back()" to add each element.  You could also add "bool aux" as a member of your "mat" struct, and then you wouldn't need a separate "aux" collection.

There's also nothing in the code you've given which sets "r" and "c", so unless those are set in code that wasn't shown, you're only setting your rows and columns fields to the default value of r and c anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop you used indices `s-'A'` for vector matrices

```
for(int i=0; i<n;++i) {
    cin >> s >> r >> c;
    matrices[s-'A'].row = r;
    matrices[s-'A'].column = c;
    aux[s-'A'] = true;
```

}

As I guess s had values in the range 'A' - 'Z'

However inside the function you used indices `i+'A' fo vector matrices

```
cout << char ('A'+i) << " Rows: " << matrices[i+'A'].row << " Columns: " << matrices[i+'A'].column << endl;
```

I think that indices in vector matrices must coinside with indices in vector aux. That is the body of the function should look as

```
void writeMatrices( const vector<mat> &matrices )
{
    for ( std::vector<bool>:size_type i = 0; i < aux.size(); ++i )
    {
        if( aux[i] ) 
        {
            cout << char ('A'+i) << " Rows: " << matrices[i].row << " Columns: " << matrices[i].column << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that container  `std::map<char, mat>` would be more suitable for your task.